# flutter: requests are spamed when the widget rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, request

So I am pretty new to flutter and I have this problem where the  HTTP requests are spammed from previous screens when the widgets are rebuild by opening the keyboard.

For instance I have one screen called ActivityDetailsScreen in which I have a request that gets 1 activity. On that screen I also have a button to go to another page and there I can edit a textfield and every time I open or close the keyboard the widget reloads and the request from the previous page is executed.

Is there a way to avoid this?

**EDIT:**

I execute the request in the constructor of the screen

```
ActivityDetailsScreen({
    this.activityIndexString,
    this.idActivity,
    this.idUserProject,
    this.idProject,
    this.idUser,
    this.isOpenProject,
    this.deadLine,
    this.feedback,
  }) {
    ActivitiesService activitiesService = Get.find();
    this.activity = activitiesService.getActivity(this.idActivity);
  }
```

this is how I go to the next screen.

```
...
child: CupertinoButton(
                  child: Text(
                    isOpenProject
                        ? S.current.workOnProject
                        : S.current.viewProject,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        context
                            .bloc<AddImagesBloc>()
                            .add(LoadImagesEvent(idUserProject: idUserProject));
                        return AddImagesScreen(
                          idUserProject: idUserProject,
                          activityTitle: activityEntity.title,
                          isOpenProject: isOpenProject,
                          feedback: this.feedback,
                        );
                      },
                    ));
                  },
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                ),
                ...
```

activities_service.dart file is where the HTTP request is called. this function is called in the constructor of the ActivityDetailsScreen constructor (shown in the first code snippet).

```
Future<ActivityEntity> getActivity(String id) async {
    QueryResult result = await this.client.query(
          QueryOptions(
            document: tgql(GQLQuery.activity),
            variables: {"id": id},
          ),
        );
    var data = result.data['activity'];
    if (useMockData)
      return mockActivities.firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    return ActivityEntity.fromJson(data);
  }
```

Comment: Could you show your code? Without that, we can't tell what's going on.

Comment: But you're not showing where that HTTP call is being performed...

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I added it now, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand your flow... are you trying to open a new screen? Why don't you create a new Stateful Widget for that and then do you logic inside the initState method. Everything you do logic wise inside a build method will be executed again if something rebuilds that method.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be performing the HTTP call *outside* of `ActivityDetailsScreen` and just passing in the results via constructor args, and not performing any type of async work inside of the constructor itself.

I'm assuming you're using the Get package for state management (judging by your `Get.find()` call).

A `GetxController` would be the right place to make an HTTP call and storing the results for use wherever/whenever, completely outside of the lifecycle of display widgets such as ActivityDetailsScreen.

Widgets, especially StatelessWidgets, can be destroyed/recreated or rebuilt very often.  The opening/closing of the software keyboard is a perfect example.  It causes the constraints (available space to render) for widgets to change, therefore the widgets are rebuilt.

---

I'm not really clear on what's happening with the `.bloc & .add` in your code here, but it's probably not the right place to be doing that either.  I'm guessing you're trying to navigate to a new page / route (the destination being `AddImagesScreen`).

```
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        context
                            .bloc<AddImagesBloc>()
                            .add(LoadImagesEvent(idUserProject: idUserProject));
                        return AddImagesScreen(
                          idUserProject: idUserProject,
                          activityTitle: activityEntity.title,
                          isOpenProject: isOpenProject,
                          feedback: this.feedback,
                        );
                      },
                    ));
                  },
```

And you're seeing the `ActivityDetailsScreen` being rebuilt/HTTP call happening when you're opening/closing a keyboard on the `AddImagesScreen`?

Comment: Yes I see the ActivityDetailsScreen being rebuilt|HTTP requests being called in the AddImagesScreen.
I will try your advice this week and let you know if i made it :) thanks